# Set default print scalling for the generated Excel file in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I generate an Excel file via Apache POI successfully. The problem is that, when I try to print it, the last 3 columns is not within the printable area. For example, the worksheet has columns A to L but it only fits column A to when printing. The users always change the print scaling from "No Scaling" to "Fit All Columns on One Page" before printing.

[image]

How can I modify the Excel file in such a way that all columns would fit on the printable area, and the users won't need to change the scaling every time they print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of [Sheet.setFitToPage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setFitToPage(boolean)) and [PrintSetup.setFitWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.html#setFitWidth(short)) and `PrintSetup.setFitHeight`.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class PrintSetupFitWidth {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  //create at least one cell so print preview is possible
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Cell A1");

  //set page setup to fit to one page width but multiple pages height
  sheet.setFitToPage(true);
  sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitWidth((short)1);
  sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short)0);

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("PrintSetupFitWidth.xlsx");
  workbook.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```