# NPOI C# set columns to fit on one page

Tags: c#, apache-poi, npoi

I am using NPOI Version 2.5.3 in my C# application and am trying to set the scaling option (**Fit All Columns on 1 Page**). Which seems easy enough to do from these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432953/how-can-it-set-the-file-for-fit-all-columns-on-one-page-setting) and [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201308.mbox/%3C1375955582.58916.YahooMailNeo@web122301.mail.ne1.yahoo.com%3E).

**The problem:**

So, my problem occurs when using the code below. All that does is configures; both the width and height to fit to one page. I assumed it was because of the **sheet.FitToPage = true**.

```
private void SetPrintSettings(XSSFSheet sheet)
{
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.BottomMargin, 0.5);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.TopMargin, 0.5);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.LeftMargin, 0.45);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.RightMargin, 0.45);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.HeaderMargin, 0.3);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.FooterMargin, 0.3);

    sheet.Autobreaks = true; //auto breaks
    sheet.FitToPage = true;  //THIS SETS IT TO ALL FIT ON ONE PAGE

    var PrintSetup = sheet.PrintSetup;
    PrintSetup.FitWidth = 1; //fit width onto 1 page
    PrintSetup.FitHeight = 0; //don't care about height
    PrintSetup.Landscape = true;
    PrintSetup.PaperSize = 3; //paper size 11x17
}
```

When doing the code above I get the following output in Excel.

[image]

So after that did not work I tried setting it to false like shown below.

```
 private void SetPrintSettings(XSSFSheet sheet)
 {
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.BottomMargin, 0.5);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.TopMargin, 0.5);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.LeftMargin, 0.45);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.RightMargin, 0.45);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.HeaderMargin, 0.3);
    sheet.SetMargin(MarginType.FooterMargin, 0.3);

    sheet.Autobreaks = true; //auto breaks
    sheet.FitToPage = false; 

    var PrintSetup = sheet.PrintSetup;
    PrintSetup.FitWidth = 1; //fit width onto 1 page
    PrintSetup.FitHeight = 0; //don't care about height
    PrintSetup.Landscape = true;
    PrintSetup.PaperSize = 3; //paper size 11x17
}
```

When change the configuration, it renders "No Scaling" as shown below.

[image]

No matter what I try I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried a variety of settings and nothing seems to work. I am beginning to think its a bug with the version I am using. It doesn't help that almost all the examples I find are for Java POI so I am unsure if it is just an approach issue.

**Desired Output:**

Below is what I am trying to do. Just set the scaling option to Fit columns onto 1 page. If anyone could help me out or point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

[image]

Comment: In `apache poi` this is set using a combination of `Sheet.setFitToPage` and `PrintSetup.setFitWidth` and `PrintSetup.setFitHeight`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847210/set-default-print-scalling-for-the-generated-excel-file-in-apache-poi/41856100#41856100. Not sure whether `NPOI` uses the same.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I did but it did not work the same way. @Axel Richter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in NPOI.

In order to achieve the setting you are after you need the `PageSetup` element in the sheet XML to have the `fitToHeight` attribute set to 0. E.g.:

```
<pageSetup orientation="landscape" fitToHeight="0"/>
```

Unfortunately, if I've read the NPOI code correctly, it looks like NPOI isn't outputting the attribute because it thinks it's a blank value.

When you call `PrintSetup.FitHeight = 0;` it sets the `fitToHeight` property in `Sheet.cs`. When writing the file, in [Sheet.cs](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/d28b0530e9725f9c27b0151e2ca8713a9b667987/OpenXmlFormats/Spreadsheet/Sheet.cs#L5545) there is the following:

```
XmlHelper.WriteAttribute(sw, "fitToHeight", this.fitToHeight, 1);
```

The [`WriteAttribute`](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/d28b0530e9725f9c27b0151e2ca8713a9b667987/openxml4Net/Util/XmlHelper.cs#L359) code looks like this:

```
public static void WriteAttribute(StreamWriter sw, string attributeName, uint value, uint defaultValue, bool writeIfBlank = false)
{
    if(value != defaultValue)
        WriteAttribute(sw, attributeName, (int)value, writeIfBlank);
    else if(writeIfBlank)
        WriteAttribute(sw, attributeName, (int)value, writeIfBlank);
}
```

`value` (0) is not equal to `defaultValue` (1) in our case so we enter the first `if`. That calls another overload of [`WriteAttribute`](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/d28b0530e9725f9c27b0151e2ca8713a9b667987/openxml4Net/Util/XmlHelper.cs#L331) which looks like this:

```
public static void WriteAttribute(StreamWriter sw, string attributeName, int value, bool writeIfBlank)
{
    if (value == 0 && !writeIfBlank)
        return;

    WriteAttribute(sw, attributeName, value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

`value` *is* equal to `0` and `writeIfBlank` is false so, again, the first `if` is true and thus the `return;` is hit and no value is written out.

Answer (score 0):

> **1)** You could be *missing* `autoSizeColumn`, if I understood you correctly. Please configure/setup to `autosize` the cols to fit you need to use `youExcelSheet.AutoSizeColumn()`  and, that in **2)** *combination* with the autofit to page/sheet  `FitToPage`  should make it work for you.

Source code from [Apache Github](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI/blob/9fc667e32476f1a251730141df12e1927349c75c/src/NPOI/SS/UserModel/Sheet.cs#L657), since the calculation of the col & page sizes the order of calls *maybe* important between `autoSizeCol` and `autofit` page you can try both combos
[image]

From the apache ref. can autosize your cols ref from Apache [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Autofit),

---

```
// create some cells
for (int r=0; r < 10; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c; c < 10; c++) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
        cell.setCellValue("Cell " + c.getAddress().formatAsString());
    }
}


// 1 ** AUTO-Size the columns individually like below.
// 2 Or get/fit ALL, then loop through the cols, divide the sheet by number of cols


sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
```

---

and an older sample in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651803/6085193)

```
HSSFWorkbook spreadsheet = new HSSFWorkbook();

DataSet results = GetSalesDataFromDatabase();

//here, we must insert at least one sheet to the workbook. otherwise, Excel will say 'data lost in file'
HSSFSheet sheet1 = spreadsheet.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

foreach (DataColumn column in results.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in results.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        HSSFRow dataRow = sheet1.CreateRow(rowIndex);
        dataRow.CreateCell(column.Ordinal).SetCellValue(row[column].ToString());
        rowIndex++;
    }
    sheet1.AutoSizeColumn(column.Ordinal);
}

//Write the stream data of workbook to the file 'test.xls' in the temporary directory
FileStream file = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "test.xls") , FileMode.Create);
spreadsheet.Write(file);
file.Close();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with auto sizing the columns. Its a page setup setting. Although unrelated my columns are in fact auto sized in code done before this. I am trying to set a property of the excel sheet for the scaling option. The scaling option needs to say fit all columns on one page.